# Chrome extension don't work when tested in chrome://extensions/

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jsonp

I'm trying to learn a little a bit about google-extensions, so I tried to make a simple extension that make a request to an `api` using `ajax` then return some results.

When I test directly in the browser(localhost), it works perfectly, but when I try to test adding it to `chrome://extensions/` and clicking on *Load unpacked extension…* in developer mode, it's not working.

This is my `app.js` with `ajax` call:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    $( '#form-custom' ).on( 'submit', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        user = $('#user').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'https://sitewiththeapi.net/api/searchuser/'+user+'/show/list.json',
            dataType:'jsonp'
        })

        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        })

        .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            console.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        })
    }
}, false);
```

And my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "This extension will for learning",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "app.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "http://*/",
   "https://*/"
   ]
}
```

**EDIT:** Added `https` to `manifest.json` file and the error persists.
Inspecting the popup I got the following error:

> jquery.min.js:4 Refused to load the script
>   'https://sitewiththeapi.net/api/searchuser/theuser/show/list.json'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: Your manifest doesn't have permissions for `https`.

Comment: Updated and the error persists. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
"converted_from_user_script": true,
```

After version in your manifest.json.

This is more of a hack than a legit solution but its fine if you are developing that extension for yourself or just to learn.

Comment: Thanks!! This solved the problem! Can I ask what this parameter do in `manifest`? Oh, a note: **Changing the `datatype` to `json` returned the `json` response to me too, but only when I'm not at `localhost`**. Don't know why.

Comment: There isn't much info on this but you can read [this](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Cross-browser_userscripting) to understand where its coming from. Like I said this is more of a hack than a legit solution. Glad I could help.