# chrome extension execute script not working with content_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Aim is to inject a content script into a eventpage script in google chrome extension with no popup menu when button is clicked. Current error message is

```
tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
```

In the content_script a fetch request is made, if you have any tips on that as well it would be greatly appreciated.

## Event Page Content Script

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

## Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Seneca One add Bookmark",
  "description": "Posts URL to database.",
  "version": "2.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Favicon@2x.png",
    "default_title": "Add bookmark"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error says you're trying to inject the content script on a built-in chrome:// page, which is not allowed.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46158196/6586663).

Answer (score 0):

@woxxom is correct when he says you are opening a script on a chrome extension.
Make a popup.html with the browser action and then just make it run and then close itself instantly. Make sure your popup.js is in the default_script : popup.js in your manifest.
Then you could make background { persistent : true } in your manifest to make your script working the background on every page and listening for your fetch. So essentially the same effect of what you are looking for. You click the icon your popup.html/popup.js runs the fetch / instantly disappears, while your background js is running in the background answering.