# Chrome Extension blocks programmatic request to popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After the release of Chrome 66, our specs for testing a Chrome Extension fail because we are unable to access the popup.html programmatically because the request to `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/src/popup.html` is blocked.

[image: Request is blocked when accessing popup.html programmatically]

We've tried getting the extension ID programmatically using `chrome.runtime.id` and `chrome.runtime.getURL()`.

We've also tried generating our own PEM to sign the extension and using the generated ID in the manifest as the extension key. Both of these attempts have proved fruitless.

Is there still a way to access Chrome Extension programmatically for testing?

Update: Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Paparazzi",
  "version": "1.0.9",
  "background": {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "scripts": [
      "src/background.js",
      "vendor/jszip.js",
      "vendor/FileSaver.js",
      "vendor/mixpanel.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "ic-paparazzi-16.png",
      "48": "ic-paparazzi-48.png",
      "96": "ic-paparazzi-96.png",
      "128": "ic-paparazzi-128.png",
      "256": "ic-paparazzi-256.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
  },
  "commands": {
    "capture_screen": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+E"
      },
      "description": "Capture screenshot of current tab"
    }
  },
  "content_security_policy":
    "script-src 'self' https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js; object-src 'self'",
  "icons": {
    "16": "ic-paparazzi-16.png",
    "48": "ic-paparazzi-48.png",
    "96": "ic-paparazzi-96.png",
    "128": "ic-paparazzi-128.png",
    "256": "ic-paparazzi-256.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "identity",
    "identity.email",
    "notifications",
    "tabCapture",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://*/",
    "*://*.sharethrough.com/*",
    "*://localhost/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "src/*",
    "vendor/fonts/MetricWeb-Regular.woff",
    "vendor/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "key": "bgcanlbkmndllogdnbohopfomoknmjmf"
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, either in Chrome or in that remote control software.

Comment: Since this is a new problem it probably won't work but you can still try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46158196/6586663).

Comment: @PredatorIWD didn't work, but thank you!

Comment: Chrome 66 finally [stopped loading extensions with manifest_version:1](https://crbug.com/816677) - maybe that's your case?

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm on manifest version 2!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Chrome 66.0.3359.117 and I was able to get files like this;

```
chrome.runtime.getURL("popups/popup.html");
```

`window.open()` succeed for getting it to open the page. It does not work when the folder or file is not specified under `"web_accessible_resources"`.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "popups/*"
]
```

If the problem isn't with the manifest, then it's likely related to the testing software and not Chrome.